# compilation misunderstanding over types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have this school assignment which requires me to multiply two polynomial A and B together using the property:

```
if A = a +pX then AB = aB + XPB
```

to implement this I've written this recursive program which implement a polynomial as a list of it's coefficients:

```
let rec mul p q = match (p,q) with
|a::b,q -> add (mulscal q a) (mul b [0.]::q)
|[],q -> p;;
```

But I get this error:

```
Line 4, characters 11-44:
4 | |a::b,q -> add (mulscal q a) (mul b [0.]::q)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type float list
       but an expression was expected of type float
```

which is weird considering that's exactly what I want (a list of floats which represent the polynomial).

If anyone has an idea to make Ocaml understand that's the program is "right" I would highly appreciate it.

PS: sorry for the lack of details but the subject is in French and translating it would require too much time.

Comment: The definition of `add` would be a useful detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out you just need to replace

```
|a::b,q -> add (mulscal q a) (mul b [0.]::q)
```

by

```
|a::b,q -> add (mulscal q a) (mul b (0.::q))
```

Comment: Did you actually test it? Looking at the code, I think if we take the OP's code and only replace this line as you suggest, then `mul p q` will always return `[]`.